# Multiplicar un campo y sumarlo en otro Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo un formulario el cual tiene un `total_balance` el cual muestra el cumulo de puntos que voy obteniendo a la hora de cargar la cantidad "quantity"(kg, mtrs, litros, unidad, etc.). A esto se le multiplica el material con u correspondiente valor Aluminio-kg-500pts.. la operación seria 50kg de aluminio * los 500pts que vale según mi otra tabla.

form de carga:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@point) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :total_balance %> <----- # aca se cargaria el total de todo
    <%= f.input :quantity %>
    <%= f.input :type_point %>
    <%= f.association :material, label_method: :name, value_method: :id %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Modelo de material:

```
class Material < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :type_material
    belongs_to :unit_of_measurement
    def name
        "#{type_material.name}- #{unit_of_measurement.name}- #{value}pts"       
    end
end
```

Modelo de Point:

```
class Point < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :material
end
```

Comment: Marcelo, bienvenido a Stack Overflow. ¿quieres guardar el valor resultante en la tabla point o sólo mostrarlo en el formulario? ¿quieres que se actualice en vivo en el formulario mientras vayas cambiando la cantidad/material (un poco más complejo, ya que tendrías que usar algo de javascript) o solo hacer el cálculo cuando sea guardado el valor?

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida.. si quiero guardar ese valor en la tabla y que esos puntos se vayan mostrando a la vez (total_balance) seria obtener el valor de f.input :quantity y multiplicarlo por el valor que obtengo de material (tabla Material tiene value como campo)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, si lo que quieres es obtener el valor de algún elemento del **DOM** y asignarlo a otro, te recomiendo [jQuerymy](http://jquerymy.com/) , que replica el uso de **DataBinding** con **jQuery**. Dale un vistazo a la pagina tiene buenos ejemplos que te ayudaran a tu pregunta.

Sin embargo dejare un ejemplo acá de guía, para obtener el valor de tus **inputs** y al tiempo que escribes en ellos ir mostrando su valor en un párrafo.

Pero antes recuerda mirar los demos de [jQuerymy](http://jquerymy.com/).

En tu **html.erb**

```
<!-- define el alcance, encierra los datos que vas a manipular con un div -->
<div id="formulario">
  <%= simple_form_for(@point) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>
    <!-- asignale un id a los elementos que manipularas  -->
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :total_balance %> 
      <%= f.input :quantity %>
      <%= f.input :type_point %>
      <%= f.association :material, label_method: :name, value_method: :id %>
    </div>
    <!-- mostrando los datos en tiempo real -->
    <p id="total_balance"></p>
    <p id="quantity"></p>
    <p id="type_point"></p>
    <p id="unir-texto"></p>
    <p id="multiplicacion"></p>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

En una etiqueta **javascript** asumiendo que `@point == Point.new`

```
//declara arreglo donde se alamacenaran los datos de los inputs
var datos = { "total_balance": null, "quantity": null, "type_point": null};

//ahora enlaza los inputs con el arreglo
var comportamiento = {};

for( var key in datos){
  comportamiento["#point_"+key] = {bind: key}; //asocia input con arreglo 
  comportamiento["#"+key] = {bind: key,
  watch: "#point_"+key
  }; // enlaza arreglo con los parrafos
};
//agregando los dos parrafos personalizados[ unir-text , multiplicacion]
comportamiento["#unir-texto"] = {
  bind: function (data) {
    return (data.total_balance + " " + data.quantity + " " + data.type_point);
  },
  watch: "#point_total_balance, #point_quantity, #point_type_point"
};
comportamiento["#multiplicacion"] = {
  bind: function (data) {
    return (data.total_balance * data.quantity * data.type_point);
  },
  watch: "#point_total_balance, #point_quantity, #point_type_point"
};

// inicializar dataBinding
$("#formulario").my({ui:comportamiento}, datos);
```

Como ves solo es cuestión de que armes la cadena a mostrar a tu antojo.

**Posdata:** en las dependencias la versión `Sugar Library v1.4.0` fue compatible para mi. Presenté problemas con la ultima versión.

**Probado en:**

Rails v5.1.6 ruby v2.3.3